# Rails how to create a class method self to keep things DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I repeat this code many times. The only thing that changes is the name in conditions.

```
find(:all, :conditions => {:name => 'hans'}, :group => 'dato').map(&:klik)
```

I am trying to make some class method in the model. So I can keep it DRY.

I have been trying this and it is not working.

```
def self.grafdata(name)
    find(:all, :conditions => {:name => '(name)'}, :group => 'dato').map(&:klik)
end
```

ERROR: uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Lars

I want to be able to write Model.grafdata(Hans), Model.grafdata(Lars)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would simply add it as a function to your model:

```
class Model
  def self.grafdata(name)
    where(name: name).group('dato').map(&:klik)
  end
end
```

You can then call either of the following:

```
Model.grafdata('Lars')
Model.grafdata('Hans')
```

Comment: How do I set conditions and order by date?

Comment: You set conditions with where(...). My example matches the database name to the name you pass in. You order by date with the order function: where(...).order('dato DESC').group('dato')...

Comment: Why use Where instead of find?

Comment: It's scoped so it doesn't execute a query right away, so it's easy to expand on it. It's also a cleaner and easier to read format, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use named_scope:

```
class Model

  named_scope :grafdata, lambda {|name| {:conditions => ["name = ?", name], :group => 'dato'}}

end
```

Then called:

```
Model.grafdata('Lars').map(&:klik)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a module

```
module MyFinders
  def grafdata(name)
    find(:all, :conditions => {:name => '(name)'}, :group => 'dato').map(&:klik)
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend MyFinders
end
```

HTH

Peer

Comment: Where should the module go? I have updated the post with an error log.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of '(name)' it should only be (name)

```
def self.grafdata(name)
    find(:all, :conditions => {:name => (name)}, :group => 'dato').map(&:klik)
end
```

And the view: `<%= Reklamer.grafdata('Lars') %>`